# How do I clear form data in form_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to clear my form data after submission.

`_form.html.erb`:

```erb
<%= form_tag(invite_user_path, method: 'post', remote: true ) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag(:q, "Company Name:") %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:company_name, '', class: "form-control", autofocus: true)  %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag(:q,  "Contact Name:") %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:contact_name, '', class: "form-control")  %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag(:q,  "Email:") %>
    <%= email_field_tag(:email, '', class: "form-control")  %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= submit_tag("Request Invitation", class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right") %>
    <%= button_tag "Clear", type: :reset, class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm" %>
  </div>
  <br><br>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```ruby
UserMailer.invite_users_mail(invite_users_params).deliver if validate_invite_users
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to new_user_session_path, notice: 'Successfully send notification mail.' }
  format.json { head :no_content }
end
```

I redirect the application to same page when after sending mail. So i need to clear the form.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove `remote: true` from the form's parameters. This way the form will not be submitted through AJAX.